# Switch to touch events with SnapSvg

Tags: javascript, snap.svg

I need to use touch events for touch screens, and mouseevents for regular Desktop for my website using Snap SVG.

I have mouse events like :

```
_Button.mousedown(function(){
    // Do Stuff
});
```

How can I easily switch to touch events such as 'touchstart' when my user comes from a tablet ?

I don't want to duplicate code, and checks if its a touchscreen, like having 20* times this kind of code :

```
_Button.mousedown(function(){
    // Do Stuff
});

if ( touchSreenFlag === true) {
    _Button.mousedown(function(){
        // Do Stuff
    });
}
```

Thx

Comment: The Mousedown event is triggered twice on ios.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here we go :

```
SVGTHING.mouseup(function(e){

        if (e.type === 'touchend') {
            // Stop propagation : on touch devices the first click will be used and not the second.
            e.stopPropagation();
            e.preventDefault();
        }

        do_stuff();
    });
```